# How do I search and audit the transaction logs I submit through QuickNode?

Tags: transactions, logs

I'm using QuickNode to submit transaction logs, does anybody know how to search and audit these logs? - elchuo160

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by 'submit transaction logs' and 'search and audit'? Do you need to get event logs from smart contracts? Add more details to your question if you can. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the Blocktorch Add-on from QuickNode Marketplace.

Checkout this page for more info: https://marketplace.quicknode.com/add-on/blocktorch-blockchain-observability